# How to set textView from outer async task

Tags: android

I am calling the async task from onCreate method of my activity and in async I am parsing the son array. and I want to update the textView of my activity with the string i am getting.
This is my code

```
public VerifyAnswerAsync(Context context, int userId){
    this.context = context;
    this.userId = userId;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        url = new URL("URL");
        urlConnection = url.openConnection();

        inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        line = "";

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
        inputStream.close();
        result = stringBuilder.toString();
        Log.d("TAG",result);

        jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
             que1 = jsonObject.optString("que1");
             ans1 = jsonObject.optString("ans1");


            que2 = jsonObject.optString("que2");
             ans2 = jsonObject.optString("ans2");
            Log.d("Tag",que1);
            Log.d("Tag",ans1);
            Log.d("Tag",que2);
            Log.d("Tag",ans2);
        }


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.publishProgress(que1,que2,ans1,ans2);
    return result;
}
```

How should I update the text view in the activity from async task.Please help.

I tried to do this from postExecute but textView was nil.

Comment: As usual: inside `onPostExecute`

Comment: you can update it from onPostExecute() method .

Comment: I did that but the textView appears nil.

Comment: Then Debug your code  for value which you setText() in your TextView.

Comment: the value is present in string i can see it in log.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `onPostExecute` callback of the `AsyncTask`  call `setText(String text)` on your `TextView` object.

Comment: Like This--->@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
      

//       super.onPostExecute(s);
        
        textViewQue1.setText(que1);
    }Not working

Comment: Yes please. 
And be sure to execute your `AsyncTask` after you've assigned your TextView object with `findViewById`.